# How to select option by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JSP page, I set select option 'selected' by value using JS like:

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
        document.getEleMentById('test').options[1].selected = 'selected';
    });
</script>
```

e is:sele

```html
<Select id='test'>
    <option value='ruby'>ruby</option>
    <option value='saab'>saab</option>
    <option value='nrro'>nrro</option>
<select>
```

The result is: option *saab* is selected, but the browser show *ruby* (default selected).

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8kh6bhc/) with correct `getElementById`. And with "more jQuery" just for completeness: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8kh6bhc/1/)

Comment: next time you should view the console window first (almost significant  errors are reported there), you should have solved this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in `getElementById` function, that code is correct:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test'>
 <option value='ruby'>ruby</option>
 <option value='saab'>saab</option>
 <option value='nrro'>nrro</option>
<select>
<script>
   $(function(){
      document.getElementById('test').options[1].selected = 'selected';
   });
</script>
```